# Running Child Process In Sequential Statement Before Exiting Parent?

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I'm trying to write a Bash script that, when it receives a SIGINT signal, creates a copy of itself before exiting. So, when a user tries to kill this script using a SIGINT signal a copy of the process reapppears.

```
trap "echo Exiting...?; ./ghoul.sh; exit 1" SIGINT 

while : 
    do
    echo Process Number $$, with PPID $PPID!
    sleep 1
done
```

However, whenever I suspend the process and check `ps -f`, there are multiple processes of the script (children and children of children). The exit command never seems to run since it's waiting for the children to exit. I want to find a way to run the script in the `trap` statement and exit afterward while maintaining the resulting child process. Is there any way to do this besides creating the child as a background process?

Answer (score 1):

I find it much simpler to put exit code into a function.  For example, your unquoted echo contains a bare `?` which is a glob (file expansion) character.  To avoid the parent killing the child you can use  `disown`, and yes, you need to run it in background.

Try this:

```
f_exit() {
    echo 'Exiting...?'
    ./ghoul.sh &
    disown -h %1
    exit 1
}
trap "f_exit" SIGINT

while :
    do
    echo "Process Number $$, with PPID $PPID!"
    sleep 1
done
```